# Calculating Fib3 Number Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate fib 3 number but nothing is printing.
here is my code.

```
<div class="container">


<script type="text/javascript">
        function fib(n) {

              if(n == 0 || == 1){
                  return 1;
              }

              return fib(n=1) + fib(n=2) + fib(n-3);

          }

          function start(){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML(fib(3));

          }

          window.addEventListener("load", start, false)
</script>


<div > 
  <input type="text" id="result" />
</div>

</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea of where am going wrong?

Comment: Did you try firebug, because the errors are crystal clear and it should show them?

Answer (score 1):

`fib(n=1)` and `fib(n=2)` are wrong.

`if(n == 0 || == 1){` is a syntax error.

Comment: For `fib(n=1)`, I think you mean `fib(n-1)`. The latter should obviously be `if (n == 0 || n == 1)` or alike (say should it include `n == 2` too? Since you did not define what `fib` should compute, there is no way I can help you.

Comment: it must be fibonacci number :)

Comment: Fibonacci number does not write as `fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) + fib(n-3)`. OP says "fib 3 number" so it is likely something slightly different.

Comment: I know, it just reminded me that. But keep in mind that OP may not even be knowing the fibonacci number calculation :) just saying.

Comment: Yeah, so as a homework helper, we had better stop where we should.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 'n' in if statement.

If should be

```
if(n==0 || n==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done changes and defined the fibonnaci and this has worked. Thank you for the answers.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

            function fib(n){

                if(n <= 1){
                    return 1;
                }
                else {
                    return (fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 3));
                }
            }

            function start(){
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = fib(4000)
            }

            window.addEventListener("load", start, false)
        </script>
```